# keeps on getting an error (jQuery variable to PHP variable)

Tags: php, jquery

i still can't get the jquery variable.it keeps on giving me an error

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $("#months").change(function(event)
    {
          $.ajax
          ({
            type: 'post',
             url: "monthly_CRD.php",
             data:
            {
                 "m": $(this).val()
             },
             success: function(msg)
             {
                 alert(msg);
             },
             error: function(msg) 
            {
                 alert("An error happened: " +msg);
            }   
       });
    });

    <div>
<select id="months">
    <option value='00'>Month...</option>
            <option value='01'>Jan</option>
            <option value='02'>Feb</option>
            <option value='03'>Mar</option>
            <option value='04'>Apr</option>
   </select>
   </div>

   <?php
     if (isset($_POST['m'])) 
      {
         $m = $_POST['m'];
         echo $m;
      }
   ?>
```

the error is An error happened: [objectXMLHttpRequest]

this is the jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("select").change(function(event)
    {
        var view=$(this).val();
        switch(view)
        {
            case "daily":
            {
                $("#graph").load('../crd_reports/daily_CRD.php');
                $("#top10").empty();
                break;
            }
            case "weekly": 
            {
                $("#graph").load('../crd_reports/weekly_CRD.php');
                $("#top10").load('../crd_reports/top10_weekly.php');
                break;
            }
            case "monthly":
            {
                $("#graph").load('../crd_reports/monthly_CRD.php');
                $("#top10").load('../crd_reports/top10_monthly.php');
                break;
            }
            case "yearly":
            {
                $("#graph").load('../crd_reports/yearly_CRD.php');
                $("#top10").load('../crd_reports/top10_yearly.php');
                break;
            }
            default: 
            {
            }
        }

    }); 
});
```

Comment: can you alert and see $(this).val()

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: and to see the error. instead of doing an alert write console.log and check your console in firfox or chrome. console.log(msg)

Comment: if i remove the ajax and alert the $(this).val it would return the value of the option selected.

Comment: this is the error
An error happened: [objectXMLHttpRequest]

Comment: @shobe089 I suggest you read the API for the `ajax()` "error" callback - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: nothing happened when i used console.log(msg)

Comment: @shobe089 Here's a hint; argument #1 to the error callback is **not** an error message. Also, there are three arguments for you to use, not just one

Comment: the important thing is i need to retrieve the jQuery variable and pass it to the PHP variable.i could just remove the error function.it's not really important.

Comment: Try firebug, and look at the request and response.

Comment: no firebug version compatible with version 6.0 yet. and i already used chrome fiddler.

Answer (score 2):

You saved the value with

```
var m = $(this).val();
```

...so you should put this into your data:

```
data: {
  "m": m
}
```

Comment: @shobe089 - what happens if you put it back?

Comment: if i removed the variable and use this the alert function for error would give me An error happened: [objectXMLHttpRequest]

Answer (score 0):

"this" change context inside the ajax function to represent the "ajax()" function instead of the selected month, so it won't have val() any more:

```
data:
{
    "m": $(this).val() // this is like -> "m": $.(ajax()).val()
},
```

retrive the "m" variable saved in the outer context instead:

```
data:
{
    "m": m
},
```

It should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The Code you've given is in a `.html` or '.php' file? what ever, please check the url of this page. if you url is like something like `file:///E:/wamp/www/test/post.html` (example) then it will not work, you have to use `http://localhost/test/post.html` i.e a server url. I think this will fix your problem

Comment: well it's like this.the file is a php file and is called through jquery.

Comment: @shobe089 i want to know that the code of jquery reside in .html or .php file. if you change the url `http://localhost/test/post.html` or `http://localhost/test/post.php` it will work, i hope

Comment: there i already posted the jquery.i edited the post above.thank you for the help.

Comment: i'm calling a php file named  reports_CRD.php then from there the viewer could change which view he or she wants without loading the whole page.